# Plone: user role drops to Anonymous when adding an item to a folderish type with custom workflow

Tags: python, plone, archetypes

I have a custom folderish archetype-based type with a two-state custom workflow attached to it. This type restricts subtype to 'File'.

Everything seems to work, except when I ( a user with 'Site Administrator' privileges) try to add an instance of type File, I'm able to get into edit menu and save the object, but when view of that object is displayed, the following access violation error is raised:

```
Unauthorized: Your user account does not have the required permission.
Access to '@@plone_redirector_view' of (SalesProduct at /testsite/testproduct) denied.
Your user account, Anonymous User, exists at (unknown).
Access requires View_Permission, granted to the following roles:
['Manager', 'Owner', 'Reviewer', 'Site Administrator'].
Your roles in this context are ['Anonymous'].
> /home/alex/projects/eggs/AccessControl-2.13.7-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/AccessControl/ImplPython.py(797)raiseVerbose()
-> raise Unauthorized(text)
```

Also child object doesn't show workflow menu.

There's similar question about folderish type support [How to directly publish only child items of my Container type in Plone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679530/how-to-directly-publish-only-child-items-of-my-container-type-in-plone) but it doesn't solve the problem as in my case it seems to be more of a permission problem than workflow issue.

UPDATE: Permission issue obscuring the real problem. Examine stack trace to fix it. Thanks Martin.

Comment: The `plone_redirector_view` is being used in the error message; when a traversal error occurs you are still anonymous, after which the redirector view fails because anon doesn't have view permissions on the context. Is there an error in the error log at all?

Comment: Nothing in the logs, but I added breakpoint at the top of stack trace, apparently one of static resources is missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Authorization error obscures real error message. Solution: examine the stack and add a debug point before authorization error is triggered.

Thanks Martijn!